# Convert sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 to sensor_msgs/LaserScan

Tags: sensor-msgs, laserscan, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I'd like to use the hector_slam package for mapping.

The package requires sensor_msgs/LaserScan data, while my sensor does a 3D scan, which is converted to sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 data.

As it looks, this is quite uncommon and usually people want to make 3D PCL2 scan from their 2D laser scans.

So, are there any packages which can do the conversion I seek?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38002/convert-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-to-sensor_msgs/laserscan/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-07-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[pointcloud_to_laserscan](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pointcloud_to_laserscan) is probably the package you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-07-05**:
I'm really feeling kind of stupid right now....really, really thank you :-)